# Lorentz transformation four momentum to to lab frame

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I would like to know how to transform from a generic four momentum of the form:

$(E, p_x, p_y,p_z)$

to the frame where the $y$-component is zero:

$(E^\prime, p\sin\theta, 0, p\cos\theta)$

What is the general form of the $4\times 4$ Lorentz transformation that does this?

For me the vector $(E, p_x, p_y,p_z)$ will be just four number I get from a Monte Carlo event generator which obey the on-shell condition i.e.

${E^\prime}^2-p^2 = m^2$

where $m$ is the mass of the particle.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a Lorentz boost by some velocity in the $y$-direction does to $E$ and $\vec p$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. All I know is the numerical value of $(E, p_x, p_y,p_z)$ 
 and that the frame I want to calculate in has the y-component of momentum zero.

Answer (score 2):

By transforming into a frame moving in the $y$-direction with the proper speed (i.e., the speed of the particle in the $y$-direction), we can make the particle's $y$-momentum be zero.

Working (like you) in units with $c=1$, the Lorentz transformation matrix for a boost to velocity $v\hat y$ looks like

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & 0 & -\gamma v & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-\gamma v & 0 & \gamma & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where

$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$$

and the row and column order is $t,x,y,z$.

This matrix can transform any contravariant four-vector, such as one containing the coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ or one containing the energy and momentum, $(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$.

You want the energy-momentum four-vector to transform so that the $y$-momentum becomes zero:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E' \\
p\sin\theta \\
0 \\
p\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & 0 & -\gamma v & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-\gamma v & 0 & \gamma & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E \\
p_x \\
p_y \\
p_z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma(E-v p_y) \\
p_x \\
\gamma(p_y-v E) \\
p_z
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

From the third row we find that $v$ must be

$$v=\frac{p_y}{E}.$$

From this and the other rows, we get the transformed energy-momentum parameters,

$$E'=\frac{E-\left(\frac{p_y}{E}\right)p_y}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{p_y}{E}\right)^2}}=\sqrt{E^2-p_y^2},$$

$$p=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_z^2},$$

and

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{p_x}{p_z}\right).$$

As a check on this calculation, you can see that the invariant length of the new energy-momentum four-vector, $E'^2-p^2$, is equal to the invariant length of the old one, $E^2-p_x^2-p_y^2-p_z^2$.

Note: I have kept your somewhat-confusing notation where $p$ is the magnitude of the transformed momentum. It would be better to call it $p'$ and the angle $\theta'$.

If you are doing research in particle physics, I encourage you to become comfortable performing Lorentz transformations of energies and momenta. The general form of a boost matrix can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations), but the special cases for boosts along the axes are simple enough to memorize. They mix only that one spatial dimension with time, and they do so in a nicely symmetrical way.

Comment: Hi, I followed your calculation and it is very clear. Thank you so much, also for the link. I will study it. Thanks again!